# Show records that haven't been updated for more than a week in reports

Tags: reporting, criteria, criteria-filter

To show records in report that haven't been updated for a week or more do is the following criteria correct?

LatModifiedDate__c - Less than - THIS WEEK

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last seven consecutive days, use Last Modified Date not equal to Last 7 Days. If you want records that haven't been updated since the previous start of week (Sunday or Monday, depending on locale), use Last Week.